# ID column with generated uniqe values in view (with union all)

Tags: database, postgresql, view

I have view on database created by script:

```
create or replace view auction_view4 as
    select row_number() over(order by f.userid) as id, f.id as propertyId,f.userid, r."type", a.street, a.homenumber, a.localnumber, a.city, a.postcode, f.price, f."size", f.rooms, f.floor 
    from address a, flat f, realassets r
    where f.addressid = a.id and a.realassetid =r.id 
    union all
    select row_number() over(order by p.userid) as id, p.id as propertyId, p.userid, r."type", a.street, a.homenumber, a.localnumber, a.city, a.postcode, p.price, p."size", null as rooms, null as floor 
    from address a, plot p, realassets r
    where p.addressid = a.id and a.realassetid =r.id 
    union all
    select row_number() over(order by h.userid) as id, h.id as propertyId, h.userid, r."type", a.street, a.homenumber, a.localnumber, a.city, a.postcode, h.price, h."size", h.rooms, null as floor
    from address a, house h, realassets r
    where h.addressid = a.id and a.realassetid =r.id
```

That is result of my view

[image]

everything is ok, but I thinking how to generate ID column with unique values?
Do You have any advice how to achive that goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
create or replace view auction_view4 as
    with data as (
    select f.id as propertyId,f.userid, r."type", a.street, a.homenumber, a.localnumber, a.city, a.postcode, f.price, f."size", f.rooms, f.floor 
    from address a, flat f, realassets r
    where f.addressid = a.id and a.realassetid =r.id 
    union all
    select p.id as propertyId, p.userid, r."type", a.street, a.homenumber, a.localnumber, a.city, a.postcode, p.price, p."size", null as rooms, null as floor 
    from address a, plot p, realassets r
    where p.addressid = a.id and a.realassetid =r.id 
    union all
    select  h.id as propertyId, h.userid, r."type", a.street, a.homenumber, a.localnumber, a.city, a.postcode, h.price, h."size", h.rooms, null as floor
    from address a, house h, realassets r
    where h.addressid = a.id and a.realassetid =r.id )
select row_number() over(order by userid), * from data
```

But this approach has the downside that the same record could have different id in two consecutive queries (because, for example, you inserted a new userid in some table involved).

A different approach could be generate an hash from two or more column:

```
select ..., md5(f.userid || r.type) ...
```

But although you have solved the problem of the uniqueness of the id between two different queries, you would be faced with performance problems if you had to use the id as a search field, filter or index